# Is it necessary to label the background when generating the labelled dataset for semantic segmentation?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, training, image-segmentation, u-net

When I label images for semantic segmentation (using u-net, if that matters), is labeling the background (anything I am not interested in) necessary? Will it improve the network's performance?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your concern. In image segmentation, you want to label each pixel. So, you will have the labels for each of your objects of interest. I think the remaining objects will just be considered _background_. If you explicitly label the background, then I suspect that this could mean that you force the background to look in a certain way, but I am not sure about the implications. To be honest, I am not sure what the [benchmark datasets like COCO](https://cocodataset.org) do. You may want to investigate that.

Comment: Maybe this dataset [ADE20K](https://groups.csail.mit.edu/vision/datasets/ADE20K/) is worth investigating too.

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting. I'll see if I can find the time to benchmark that